# Resampling of OHLC data

Tags: python, pandas, ohlc

I want to convert 1h OHLC data to xh OHLC data. I am using the resample method like it was proposed in similar threads, but it does not lead to the wanted result. The data:

```
                            open     high      low    close    Volume USD
date
2021-07-10 21:00:00  132.060  133.350  131.885  133.195  259057.35815
2021-07-10 22:00:00  133.195  134.160  132.885  134.045  813078.76500
2021-07-10 23:00:00  134.045  134.620  133.690  133.995  338032.62200
2021-07-11 00:00:00  133.995  135.515  133.745  134.390  560713.74425
```

The resample method ofr 2h:

```
df.resample('2H').agg({
    'open': 'first',
    'high': 'max',
    'low': 'min',
    'close': 'last',
    'Volume USD': 'sum'
})
```

The result:

```
                        open     high      low    close    Volume USD
date
2021-07-10 20:00:00  132.060  133.350  131.885  133.195  2.590574e+05
2021-07-10 22:00:00  133.195  134.620  132.885  133.995  1.151111e+06
2021-07-11 00:00:00  133.995  135.515  133.745  134.390  5.607137e+05
```

What I would like instead is a dataframe starting at 22:00 and having the data of 21:00 and 22:00 in it and with a second row consisting of 00:00 which uses the data of 23:00 and 00.00.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the desired result set the `closed` and `label` parameters of `resample` to `right`:

```py
df.resample('2H', label='right', closed='right').agg({
    'open': 'first',
    'high': 'max',
    'low': 'min',
    'close': 'last',
    'Volume USD': 'sum'
})
```

```
                        open     high      low    close    Volume USD
date                                                                 
2021-07-10 22:00:00  132.060  134.160  131.885  134.045  1.072136e+06
2021-07-11 00:00:00  134.045  135.515  133.690  134.390  8.987464e+05
```

The `closed` parameter controls which end of the interval is inclusive while the `label` parameter controls which end of the interval appears on the resulting index.  `right` and `left` refer to end and the start of the interval, respectively.